# get row by name not working in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get one row by passing a string, but it is returning `null`. Any idea?

**Main.java**

```
int close = 0;
String companies=company.getText().toString();
Cursor port=myDb.getRowLasttran(companies);
close=port.getInt(2);
port.close();
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public Cursor getRowLasttran(String company) {
    String where = KEY_COMPANIES + "= '" + company+"'";
    Cursor c = db.query( DATABASE_TABLE_LASTTRAN, ALL_KEYS_lasttran, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Here is the LogCat

```
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): Process: com.example.merostock, PID: 27711
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    ... 11 more
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at com.example.merostock.AddPortfolio.addportfolio(AddPortfolio.java:66)
03-24 04:00:26.246: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: you cannot c.moveToFirst() since c is an empty Cursor

Comment: no, i have data in the table

Comment: before calling c.moveToFirst log the row count (c.getCount) and you will see that Cursor c is empty

Comment: i fixed it n now its working. there was some space issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
db.query(TableName, null, "colum_name=?",new String[]{value for query}, null, null, null);
```